# pandas dataframe not posting correctly to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, series

I've an excel sheet "Calcs" with 1 column name "old". I'm trying to add new column "new" with a fixed value of "1" to existing sheet "Calcs" and am using below code which is resulting 2 issues.

1. it's not updating existing sheet rather it's creating new sheet called "Calcs1"
2. After code is executed and while opening excel file, getting this error. (no such error while opening file before execution of the code).

   > We found a problem with some content in 'test1.xlsx'. Do you want us
   > to try to recover as much as we can? if you trust the source of this
   > workbook, click Yes.

Appreciate any help

```
    import pandas as pd
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    
    file = r"C:\test1.xlsx"
    df2 = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = 'Calcs')
    df2["new"] = "1"
    
    book = load_workbook(file)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine = 'openpyxl')
    writer.book = book
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Calcs')
    writer.save()
    
    writer.close()
```

[image: Output with issues]

Comment: Can you post some example rows from your excel, please?

Comment: I posted an image with BEFORE and AFTER "rows from excel". is this enough?